# Codeigniter 4 - codeigniter4/system/Database/MySQLi/Connection.php - 225

Tags: php, migrate, codeigniter-4

When I try to use migrate on codeigniter4, i found this error

[error terminal after migrate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnAP4.png)

i have change the .env variable to my setting databases.

and this is some code from my file on Migrations folder

```
public function up()
   {
       $this->forge->addField([
           'mhsId'          => [
                   'type'           => 'INT',
                   'constraint'     => 11,
                   'unsigned'       => TRUE,
                   'auto_increment' => TRUE
           ],
           'mhsNama'       => [
                   'type'           => 'VARCHAR',
                   'constraint'     => '100',
           ],
           'mhsTglLahir' => [
                   'type'           => 'DATE',
                   'null'           => TRUE,
           ],
           'mhsProdi' => [
                   'type'           => 'INT',
                   'constraint'     => 5,
                   'null'           => TRUE,
           ],
       ]);
       $this->forge->addKey('mhsId', TRUE);
       $this->forge->createTable('mahasiswa');
   }
```

my goal is to create table mahasiswa with field like code above.

i dont know where my error. please help me..

Comment: From the error, I can ascertain that it is unable to find your migration files but from the code, it seems there may be a problem with connection too. Can you add the structure of your project also can you verify if your env variables are working ?

Comment: how to verify that my .env are working.?

Comment: You can print var_dump(getenv('envname')) This would mean that your environment variables are set, than try to see if you are able to run the query builders.